# Asp.Net Mvc areas dont see js files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-areas

view page url:

> MyApp > Areas > Admin > Views > _AddPost.cshtml

my project directories (I wrote url output strings as comment)

```
MyApp
-- Areas
-- Content
-- -- tinymce
-- -- -- jscripts
-- -- -- -- tiny_mce
-- -- -- -- -- tiny_mce.js   // localhost:4574/Content/......../tiny_mce.js
-- -- -- -- -- langs
-- -- -- -- -- -- en.js      // localhost:4574/Admin//langs/en.js
-- -- -- -- -- -- tr.js      // localhost:4574/Admin//langs/tr.js
-- -- -- -- -- themes 
-- -- -- -- -- -- editor_template.js // localhost:4574/Admin//themes/editor_template.js
```

I added following line,

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Content/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js")"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        language: "tr",   // this line call tr.js
        elements: "Body", // 
        mode: "exact",    // this line call editor_template.js
        height: 300,
        width: 500
    });
</script>
```

I get error

> localhost:4574/Admin//langs/en.js 404 (Not Found)
>   localhost:4574/Admin//themes/advanced/editor_template.js 404
>   (Not Found)

expected urls

> localhost:4574/Content/tinymce/jscripts/..../langs/en.js
>   localhost:4574/Content/tinymce/jscripts/..../editor_template.js

these are the invalid urls. Why these urls are generated.

how can I fix this fail? in another project there is no error, it works.

also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14801425/asp-net-mvc-uploadify) is the same...

Thanks.

Comment: localhost:4574/Admin//langs/en.js 404 that doesn't look like a valid uri. double slashes.

Comment: Do you see localhost:4574/Admin//langs/en.js  contains double / in between?

Comment: I know this is not valid.  I already ask this. Why this url is generated. please read my question carefully.

Comment: You may have to edit `tiny_mce.js` to include the correct relative urls to the other resources.

Comment: I use it with same way in another project. only one difference between them, this example in a partialview (this is not important for solution.) I cant understand, there are a lot of scripts I get this error for all. I cant change all js files.